# Type erasure in Swift Concurrency AsyncStream

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

Experimenting with Swift's concurrency, I would like to have a clean API for exposing an async sequence of a given element type and a throttled version of the same:

```
  var intStream: AsyncStream<Int> {
    AsyncStream<Int>(Int.self, bufferingPolicy: .bufferingNewest(5)) { continuation in
      Task.detached {
        for _ in 0..<100 {
          try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * 1_000_000_000)
          continuation.yield(Int.random(in: 1...10))
        }
        continuation.finish()
      }
    }
  }
  
  var throttledIntStream: AsyncStream<Int> {
    intStream.throttle(for: .seconds(2))
  }
```

But this does not work as throttle returns its own type:
Error:
`Cannot convert return expression of type 'AsyncThrottleSequence<AsyncStream<Int>, ContinuousClock, Int>' to return type 'AsyncStream<Int>'`

To get type erasure I could do

```
var throttledIntStream: some AsyncSequence {
  intStream.debounce(for: Duration.seconds(2))
}
```

but then I lose the element type information as well, which I would like to keep.

Any suggestions how to best solve that?

Edit: This is pointing to the solution I want, but I guess I will need to wait https://forums.swift.org/t/anyasyncsequence/50828/2

Comment: I think you'd need to invent your own `AnyAsyncSequence` extension. Seeing how [`AnySequence` is implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/ExistentialCollection.swift#L1246), it's rather convoluted (I think you'd also need `AnyAsyncIterator`), but I think it is still *doable*.

Comment: I do not need to invent it I think, I would just to have a `.eraseToAnySequence()` function... But yes, `AnySequence` would be the solution

Answer (score 1):

You could define an extension on `AsyncSequence` that wraps the underlying sequence in an `AsyncStream`/`AsyncThrowingStream`:

```swift
extension AsyncSequence {
    func toAsyncThrowingStream() -> AsyncThrowingStream<Element, Error> {
        var asyncIterator = self.makeAsyncIterator()
        
        return AsyncThrowingStream<Element, Error> {
            try await asyncIterator.next()
        }
    }
    
    func toAsyncStream() -> AsyncStream<Element> {
        var asyncIterator = self.makeAsyncIterator()
        return AsyncStream<Element> {
            try! await asyncIterator.next()
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```swift
var intStream: AsyncStream<Int> {
    AsyncStream<Int>(Int.self, bufferingPolicy: .bufferingNewest(5)) { continuation in
      Task.detached {
        for _ in 0..<100 {
          try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * 1_000_000_000)
          continuation.yield(Int.random(in: 1...10))
        }
        continuation.finish()
      }
    }
  }
  
  var throttledIntStream: AsyncStream<Int> {
    intStream.throttle(for: .seconds(2)).toAsyncStream()
  }
```

The big drawback of this approach is that to my knowledge there is no way of knowing if the underlying async sequence is a throwing or non-throwing one, thus one cannot implement a solution generic on the failure type.

This means that it is entirely the programmer's responsibility to chose the suitable adaptor `toAsyncStream` or `toAsyncThrowingStream`.

As you mentioned in your question, your problem will probably be solved when better opaque return types will land.

Answer (score 0):

What problem to use

```
var throttledIntStream: AsyncThrottleSequence<AsyncStream<Int>, ContinuousClock, Int>{
  intStream.throttle(for: .seconds(2))
}
```

Where did you get `AsyncThrottleSequence`?
Anyway you can extend AsyncStream with something like:

```
extension AsyncStream {
  typealias throttled = AsyncThrottleSequence<AsyncStream<Element>, ContinuousClock, Element>
}
```

And use it as:

```
var throttledIntStream: AsyncStream<Int>.throttled {
    intStream.throttle(for: .seconds(2))
  }
```

Comment: `.throttle` is from https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms
I agree that the typalias is a nice workaround, but not the solution I am looking for!

Comment: @NicolasDegen then use `AsyncThrottleSequence<AsyncStream<Element>, ContinuousClock, Element>` it's in the apple's paradigm, you can see it after applying several operators if try specify variable type manually.